# SQL INSERT data FROM Python List

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

How do I use one sql call to update a table from a python list? I tried using cur.executemany() with a python iterator but then I hit an API limit request on my server.

Thank you!

```
address_list = [('bob', 55), ('john', 50), ...]
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO
ADDRESS
(name, age) VALUES
(%s, %s)""", (address_list))
```

Comment: How many tuples are in your list?

Comment: 400,000 tuples.

Comment: Don't use Python for this, use Postgres' bulk CSV loading tool, it will be much faster (and easier).

Comment: How do I do this Tim? Because the list is coming from a python script. Can you share the sql command do this? When I use cur.executemany() I hit an api request limit. That is why I want to do it on one call. Thank you Tim.

Comment: Well what is the ulimate source of that Python list?  At some point, is it coming from a database?  Maybe Python doesn't have to be involved here at all.

Comment: That works. I can just export the list that used python to generate into a CSV file, and then use Postgres' bulk CSV loading tool to update the table? Is this your thinking Tim?

Comment: Why not divide upload into multiple parts. Like `MOD( index, 10) ==0 ,MOD( index, 10) ==1 `

Comment: Yes, that's my thinking.

Comment: Sorry Digvijay, I am a SQL NOOB. Can you share the code to do this? Thank you. And thank you TIm, I will try that. I appreciate your help.